# why is it so bad that using acceptance-rejection-sampling for computing integral

Tags: python, sampling, montecarlo

I want to compute `$\int_1^2 x^2 dx$` using the acceptance-rejection-sampling method, but it performs not well as my expectation.

```py
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12,8)

def acceptRejectSampling(number,p,c):
  sample=[]
  while len(sample)<number:
    y = random.uniform(2, 4)
    u = random.uniform(0, c)
    if u <= p(y):
        sample.append(y)
  return sample

def f(x):#the domain of x is [1,2]
  return x**2

def p(y):# pdf of y, the domain of y is [2,4]
  return 0.5/(y**(0.5))

S=7/3.0
X=np.random.uniform(1,2,1000)
print("area：",S)
print("monte calro estimator： ",np.mean([f(i) for i in X]))
#acceptance rejection sampling
y=np.linspace(2,4,200)
c=0.5/np.power(2,0.5)
cc=[c for i in range(200)]
samples=acceptRejectSampling(10000,p,c)
print("acceptance-rejection-sampling estimator： ", np.mean(samples))

plt.plot(y,cc, '--',label='c*g(x)')
py=[p(i) for i in y]
plt.plot(y, py,label='p(y)')
plt.hist(samples, bins=50, density=True,label='sampling')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

the output of code is:

aera： 2.3333333333333335

monte calro estimator：  2.391469143847661

acceptance-rejection-sampling estimator：  2.938527759943371

I am confused that why acceptance-rejection-sampling performs so bad and I want to consult you guys on this problem. please help me, thank you very much!